# Azure VM Windows Server 2012 Update Error 800F0922

Tags: azure, updates, windows-server-2012, azure-virtual-machine

We are having troubles applying Windows Updates to our **Azure** virtual machines (Windows Server 2012).

The error code returned is ***800F0922***, and results from googling the title of this post seem to agree that the issue is caused by the *Secure Boot* option being enabled, and the suggested workaround it to simply disable it before starting the VM.

Problem is, our servers are in Azure, and the setting in question is not configurable: anyone knows if there is a way around this?

*Note*: only specific updates seem to be affected, so if we hide the KB entries in question (all listed as 'optional'), we may be able to complete the update process... but I'd rather find a clean solution to apply to all servers systematically.

Thanks in advance,

Paolo

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed? I have the same problem.

Comment: Hi Chris - no, we have ditched all classic VM's by now, and moved on to using dedicated Azure services as part of an Enterprise Agreement... so I'm afraid I can't comment on this any further... Btw, services are **the** way to go for a whole lot of good reasons, if you're in a position to do so

Comment: We're in the "ditching" process :)

Comment: Same issue, opened a ticket with Azure. Azure tech ran 'Automated Troubleshooting Services' (http://support.microsoft.com/sdp/0B3509D835313231373135333632EC) and discovered same issue as above:
• Cause – As per the CBS log analysis shared C:\Windows\system32\wbem\en-US\NetTCPIP.mfl (1): error SYNTAX 0X8004402f: Error creating temporary file" *// Error due to which the installation is failing //*
• Resolution – Freed up some space from C:\windows\temp folder
All updates successfully installed after I moved everything out of C:\Windows\Temp (which was only 265 Mbs of files and folders)

Comment: See related question: https://serverfault.com/questions/797269/windows-update-800f0922

Answer (score 0):

You cannot alter the BIOS of the azure virtual machines. So It is impossible to update the Secure Boot to disabled by cmds after win vm created.

One solution is you can try to use azure vm Windows Server 2012 R2. Hope [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/e39aa225-d4d8-4b6f-8e38-097ae803cd59/how-can-i-update-azure-vm-bios-settings?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows) article and [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2902864) artile will help you

Comment: Thanks Alex, I knew that Azure VM BIOS cannot be altered, that's why I had written 'the setting in question is not configurable'... also, our servers are already running WS 2012 R2. I looked at update rollup KB2902864, however though the download page is titled "Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB2902864)" the file is named Windows8.1-KB2902864-x64.msu and stops with "The update is not applicable to your computer"... Any other ideas?

Comment: I tried to install that update in my win server 2012 R2 and got the same error. I checked the download file for 2012 r2 and found it the same with 'supported x64-based versions of Windows 8.1'. I think this is the issue of Microsoft. I think you can go to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contactus?forceorigin=esmc to report this issue to Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks again Alex - I have already raised the question with our MS support channel. If/when I have any updates I will post them here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows Server 2012 R2.  It was an Azure VM.  Secure Boot is not an option in Azure, and there was no bitlocker.  The ONLY thing that worked for was this.

I went into the C:\Windows\Temp directory as an administrator and made a copy.

I then deleted all of the items in this directory (About four items were still in use).

I then went back to Windows Update and got the windows update from Microsoft Update / Windows Update (Rather than WSUS).

I installed all the updates that I needed.

This worked.  One or two failed the first time - but after the reboot, they installed successfully and I am 100 percent up-to-date now.

Not sure if this works for everyone - but it worked for me.